# How to save user's input in UITextFieldi with firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I just use the text field and run the app I can enter data in the text field and it stores in the Firebase database but when I close the application the data is gone from the text box , better yet it does not show in the UItextbox, i can type it and click submit to send the information to the server. So how can I show it again after the application is closed and reopened. I am using the cloud store in Firebase btw  and using swift to code it in xcode

class viewcontroller5: UIViewController{

```
@IBOutlet weak var HowManyTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var WhatBrandTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var HowOftenTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var SubmitButton: UIButton!

// set document refenrence

let db = Firestore.firestore()





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeAction(swipe:)))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right
          self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    
    



}



// Function to get the auto generated document ID
func getDocument(){
    
    
    
    let docData : [String:Any] = [
    "LastUpdated":FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    "HoursOfSleep": HowManyTextfield.text! as String,
    "BrandOfProducts": WhatBrandTextField.text! as String,
    "HowManyTrims":HowOftenTextField.text! as String
    ]
        
    
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
   // print(userID)
    
    db.collection("Users").whereField("UID", isEqualTo: userID).getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else{
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents{
                if document == document{
                    print(document.documentID)
                    //create a profile collection and add the new information
                    let Profile = self.db.collection("Users").document(document.documentID)
                    Profile.updateData(docData){
                        err in
                        if let err = err{
                            print("error updating document: \(err)")} else { print("Document sucessfully updated")}
                }
                
        }
        }
        }
    
    
    
    }
}

    


    






    

    





@IBAction func SubmitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    globalDashboardVC?.FirstPage()
    getDocument()

}
```

}

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: You need to load the data from the Firestore when the application starts.

Comment: got it but the question is how do i load back the information back to the UITextField

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. A UITextField has a `.text` property so if you want the text field to display your name it would be `myTextField.text = "Kiesse"`. So if you know how to load the data from Firebase, you would get the data from the snapshot and assign it to the text field. Perhaps you can clarify the question so we can understand what's being asked.

Comment: @Jay i would suggest that you read the description that i have put before the code for better understanding

Comment: basically i just want the information that i have stored in the Firebase database , be shown in the textField when i log back to the app and load my profile page

Comment: The problem is the question is vague. For example *the data is gone*... Gone?.. from where? Gone from Firebase? What does that mean? If you close an app, all of the resources are deallocated so it would also be 'gone' from memory as expected. If you re-open the app, you will reestablish a connection with firebase and reload your data so... what's the actual issue?

Comment: @Jay it is gone from the UITextbox in the app, but it is still shown saved in the firebase server. The thing that i want is that when the app connects back to the server for auth and login i want the profile information that is already saved in the server to be displayed in the UItextboxes in the app

Comment: And... what's stopping you from doing that? When the app starts, it authenticates, reads the firebase data and populates the UITextFields. That's a fairly common process for an app. Is there something preventing you for creating that process?

Comment: @Jay thats were i have the issue and need help with the coding or at least an abstract example that can guide me through the process. **i am new with regards to app development btw **

Comment: You need to attempt to write the code and when you get stuck, post the problematic code here so we can take a look. As is, you question contains nothing showing how you authenticate or what your app's process is. I would suggest starting with the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth) and within the closure following `Auth.auth().signIn` is where you would load your data from Firebase. Give that a whirl and let us know.